# How to make Spyder marking unused variables?

Tags: python-3.x, editor, spyder

Currently, I do not see a mark under a calculated variable that is not used later.
Is there a way to make Spyder marking the unused variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We don't have that functionality and I don't know how easy it is to implement (probably hard).